# React hooks rendering component before useEffect finishes

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have an asynchronous request in my useEffect. I notice that the component is rendered before the useEffect finishes.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import './SearchWords.css';

const URL_REQUEST = 'http://myLink.com';

const SearchWords = (props) => {
    const { setState } = props;

    useEffect(async () => {
        const data = {
            sentence: props.sentence
        };
      
        await axios.post(`${URL_REQUEST}/getData`, { data })
            .then((res) => {
                setState(state =>({
                    ...state,
                    search: res.data
                }));
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.log(err);
            })
    }, []);

    const render = () => {
        if(props.search.length > 0) {
            const linkMarkup = props.search.map((link) => (
                <li key={link.id} className="link-list-item">
                  <a
                    href={link.link}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="link-list-item-url"
                    onClick
                  >
                    {link.name}
                  </a>
                </li>
            ));
            
            return <ul className="link-list">{linkMarkup}</ul>;
        } else {
            return <p>No data found for: {props.sentence}</p>
        }
    }

    return render()
}

export default SearchWords;
```

It is working, but it first shows `No data found for: My Search String`. Then, it reloads and shows the `<ul>` with the results. How can I avoid it to first show the "No data found" message.

Thanks

Comment: Keep track of when the request is loading through state. If the request is still loading you can display a spinner. Once you get the data back then you can display it. If no data is returned you can display your "No data found" message.

Typically you don't want to block your UI from rendering when you're making an async request. A loading spinner is a better indicator to your end user that your app is trying to load data in the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest tweak would be to conditionally render that section of the JSX depending on whether the response has come back yet:

```
const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState();
// ...
```

```
.then((res) => {
    setState(state =>({
        ...state,
        search: res.data
    }));
    setHasLoaded(true);
})
```

then change

```
return <p>No data found for: {props.sentence}</p>
```

to

```
return hasLoaded ? <p>No data found for: {props.sentence}</p> : <p>Loading...</p>;
```

Comment: Should also mention that if HTTP responses come in out of order, nothing is currently being done in their component to prevent an older response from overwriting a newer one.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's how the `useEffect` works: it will schedule a side effect to be run **after** the component has rendered.

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks):

> What does useEffect do? By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs **to do something after render**. React will remember the function you passed (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after performing the DOM updates. In this effect, we set the document title, but we could also perform data fetching or call some other imperative API.

What you can do is keep track of your effect status to show a loading indicator until it has finished.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import './SearchWords.css';

const URL_REQUEST = 'http://myLink.com';

const SearchWords = (props) => {
    const { setState } = props;
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

    useEffect(async () => {
        const data = {
            sentence: props.sentence
        };
      
        await axios.post(`${URL_REQUEST}/getData`, { data })
            .then((res) => {
                setState(state =>({
                    ...state,
                    search: res.data
                }));
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                console.log(err);
            })
    }, []);

    const render = () => {
        if(isLoading) return "Loading...";

        if(props.search.length > 0) {
            const linkMarkup = props.search.map((link) => (
                <li key={link.id} className="link-list-item">
                  <a
                    href={link.link}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="link-list-item-url"
                    onClick
                  >
                    {link.name}
                  </a>
                </li>
            ));
            
            return <ul className="link-list">{linkMarkup}</ul>;
        } else {
            return <p>No data found for: {props.sentence}</p>
        }
    }

    return render()
}

export default SearchWords;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is working as expected read more about [react lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). To handle this case as you're using functional component use `useState()` hook for API status.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
 // api call
 // now after api call set setIsLoading(false);
},[]}

if(isLoading) {
  // return show loading spinner
}

// else remaining code
```

Answer (score -4):

You want to track if your `fetch` call resolved before rendering anything on the screen.

You could use `React.useRef` to keep track of this state.

See [CodeSandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-rgb-7qvh9?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: This is definitely not the approach to take

Comment: Now that I think about it, `React.useState` could also store the state of "did my api call finish loading". 

@23k is this the approach you were thinking about?