# Component rendering before finishing the useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component (ownPrescriptionsPanel) inside which I'm rendering another component (PrescriptionsList). Inside the parent component, I have a useEffect hook to fetch data using Axios for the child component (PrescriptionsList). The problem is no matter what I try, the PrescriptionsList is always empty and only gets populated when I refresh. I have three child components (all are PrescriptionsList components) but I've shown only one in the below code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { PrescriptionsList } from "../../components/prescriptionsList/prescriptionsList";

import "./ownPrescriptionsPanelStyles.css";

export const OwnPrescriptionsPanel = () => {
  const [pastPrescriptions, setPastPrescriptions] = useState([]);
  const [openPrescriptions, setOpenPrescriptions] = useState([]);
  const [readyPrescriptions, setReadyPrescriptions] = useState([]);
  const [isBusy1, setIsBusy1] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3001/getpatientprescriptions",
      {
        id: sessionStorage.getItem("id"),
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log("getpatientprescriptions", response.data);
      var resArr = [];   //getting rid of the duplicates
      response.data.filter(function (item) {
        var i = resArr.findIndex(
          (x) => x.prescriptionId === item.prescriptionId
        );
        if (i <= -1) {
          resArr.push(item);
        }
        return null;
      });
      setPastPrescriptions(resArr);
      setIsBusy1(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if (isBusy1) {
    return <div>loading</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <PrescriptionsList
        pastPrescriptions={pastPrescriptions}
        heading="All prescriptions"
        viewOnly={true}
        prescriptionStatusOpen={false}
        showPharmacy={false}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Edit: Given below is the code for PrescriptionList component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import DescriptionTwoToneIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DescriptionTwoTone";
import PresciptionModal from "../prescriptionModal/prescriptionModal";

import "./prescriptionsListStyles.css";

export const PrescriptionsList = ({
  pastPrescriptions,
  heading,
  viewOnly,
  showPharmacy,
}) => {
  const [prescriptionDetails, setprescriptionDetails] = useState([]);
  const [prescriptionDrugList, setPrescriptionDrugList] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("close");
    setOpen(false);
  };

  console.log("pastPrescriptions", pastPrescriptions);

  const getPrescriptionDrugDetails = async (prescriptionId) => {
    await Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3001/prescriptionDrugDetails",
      {
        prescriptionId: prescriptionId,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log("prescriptionDrugDetails", response.data);
      setPrescriptionDrugList(response.data);
    });
  };

  const handlePrescriptionClick = async (prescriptionDetails) => {
    console.log("prescriptionDetails", prescriptionDetails);
    setprescriptionDetails(prescriptionDetails);
    await getPrescriptionDrugDetails(prescriptionDetails.prescriptionId);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const pastPrescriptionsList = pastPrescriptions.map((d) => (
    <div
      value={d}
      onClick={() => handlePrescriptionClick(d)}
      key={d.drugId}
      className="prescriptionListItem"
    >
      <div style={{ width: "30px" }}>
        <DescriptionTwoToneIcon fontSize="small" />
      </div>
      {d.prescriptionId}
    </div>
  ));

  const markPrescriptionComplete = async (d) => {
    await Axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3001/markcomplete",
      {
        prescriptionId: d.prescriptionDetails.prescriptionId,
        pharmacyId: d.prescriptionDetails.pharmacyId,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(
      "prescriptionId, pharmacyId",
      d.prescriptionDetails.prescriptionId,
      d.prescriptionDetails.pharmacyId
    );
    window.location.reload(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="prescriptionsListContainer">
      <div className="viewPrescriptionsLabel">{heading}</div>
      <div className="prescriptionsContainer">{pastPrescriptionsList}</div>
      {open && (
        <PresciptionModal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          prescriptionDetails={prescriptionDetails}
          prescriptionDrugList={prescriptionDrugList}
          viewOnly={viewOnly}
          // prescriptionStatusOpen={false}
          markprescriptioncomplete={markPrescriptionComplete}
          showPharmacy={showPharmacy}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956828/wait-for-api-call-data-before-render-react-hooks), [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213598/react-hooks-rendering-component-before-useeffect-finishes) and the code shown above is using [solution from geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-wait-for-a-reactjs-component-to-finish-updating/). None seem to be working

Comment: `useEffect` is expected to run after rendering. What do you mean by "only gets populated when [you] refresh"?

Comment: I think `useQuery` of `react-query` will be more appropriate for this.
It will call the api and then you can track the status of the api call then just show a loading indicator while waiting for the api response.

Here's an article that shows a sample
https://medium.com/swlh/getting-started-with-usequery-react-query-9ea181c3dd47

Comment: @yqlim what I meant was data is fetched and is available but it's not shown inside the component. All I want is to get the child component populated with data at the first place

Comment: What sets `id` into `sessionStorage`? If you could show that please.

Comment: @adsy the id is already set at login and it works fine. The Axios.post is working as expected since the id is available in the sessionStorage.

Comment: CAn you clarify when you say "refresh", you are meaning a full page browser refresh? Or did you mean "rerender"? When they do not show, is there any errors in console?

Comment: @adsy I mean full browser page refresh. No the console does not show errors. I added a console log after ```setIsBusy1(false);``` inside the useEffect and it also is getting logged properly

Comment: At this point I think you need to show `PrescriptionsList`. Nothing in view is wrong.

Comment: @adsy I added the code for the PrescriptionList component